# How to get scheduling latency with Ftrace in Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, scheduling, perf-event, ftrace

I am working on an embedded Linux (kernel-5.10.24) system where ftrace is enabled but NO `perf`.

I checked the tracefs in my system, and got followings,

```
# ls /sys/kernel/tracing/events/sched/ -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 enable
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 filter
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_kthread_stop
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_kthread_stop_ret
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_migrate_task
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_move_numa
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_pi_setprio
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_exec
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_exit
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_fork
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_free
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_hang
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_process_wait
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stat_blocked
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stat_iowait
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stat_runtime
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stat_sleep
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stat_wait
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_stick_numa
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_swap_numa
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_switch
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_wait_task
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_wake_idle_without_ipi
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_wakeup
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_wakeup_new
drwxr-x---    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 sched_waking
```

So, I am wondering if I can get the scheduling latency directly from `ftrace` without using `perf sched`? If so, what events and data could be used to measure the latency?